# FilePond can I show an error message when dropValidate is triggered?

Tags: filepond

I like to show an error message when `dropValidate` is triggered.

Currently when I upload files that include invalid file types or the sizes are bigger than 10MB, `dropValidate` gets triggered and users can't drop any files.

So if users couldn't drop/upload files, I would like to show an alert but is this possible?

```
      <FilePond
        ref={ref => (this.pond = ref)}
        files={files.map(file => file.file)}
        maxFiles={50}
        maxFileSize="10MB"
        acceptedFileTypes={['image/*', 'application/pdf']}
        server={{...
        ...  
        }}
        onupdatefiles={fileItems => {
          setFiles(fileItems);
        }}
        onaddfilestart={() => {
          setImagesUploading(true);
        }}
        onprocessfilestart={() => {
          setImagesUploading(true);
        }}
        onprocessfiles={() => {
          setImagesUploading(false);
        }}
        dropValidate={true}
        {...other}
      />
```